# Get locale from timezone -python, django, pytz

Tags: python, django, pytz

Is it possible to get locale from timezone?

Like 'en-US' from timezone 'America/Chicago'.

Comment: What if your user lives in Chicago but speaks Spanish?

Comment: That's OK. I will give him an option to choose. But how to set default one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pytz.country_timezones is your friend.

You can find a list of languages by country here:
http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/countryInfo.txt

You can use the country_timezones to map the django "America/Chicago" style timzeones to a country code, and then map the country code to the list of languages from geonames.

If this seems like a pain, I've done it for you.
https://github.com/georgemitchell/stackoverflow/tree/master/timezone_to_locale

Look at timezone_to_locale.py for details.

```
>>> from timezone_to_locale import locale_by_timezone
>>> locale_by_timezone["America/Chicago"]
['en-US', 'es-US', 'haw', 'fr']
```

As you can see, it even handles the dilemma that Kevin raised.

Comment: what is the license? If it is liberal enough, consider proposing a patch for `pytz` and/or add `setup.py` and publish on PyPI.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion J.F. -- my stuff is as liberal as it gets, but given that I'd have to dig into where the geonames data came from before I unleashed this to the world I'll have to do some investigation.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent code sample. If you've found a "proper" package, please let me know. I took the liberty to fork your project and made some updates so it's installable and can be run in django + python 3.9